# jQuery Toggle for Mobile Menu

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using this for a mobile menu which toggles open on screen width of less than 768px however i would also like it to toggle on screen width higher then 769. I did change the operator  < 769 however that doesn't work.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    $(".nav-primary .main-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');

    $(".responsive-menu-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".nav-primary .main-nav-menu").slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if(window.innerWidth > 768) {
            $(".nav-primary .main-nav-menu, .nav-primary .sub-menu").removeAttr("style");
            $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");
        }
    });

    $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
        if (event.target !== this)
        return;
            $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-open");
        });
    });

});
```

And the CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

    .title-area {
        float: none;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .header-image .title-area {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .header-image .site-title > a,
    .header-image .title-area,
    .site-container,
    .site-header,
    .site-header .widget-area,
    .title-area {
        width: 100%
    }

    .main-nav-menu,
    .site-header,
    .site-header .widget-area,
    .title-area {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .main-nav-menu {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    .nav-primary {
        float: none;
    }

    .site-title {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .entry-comments-link,
    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu,
    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu > .menu-item > .sub-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item,
    .responsive-menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-primary .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item:hover {
        position: static;
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu a,
    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu a:hover,
    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .current-menu-item > a {
        background: none;
        display: block;
        line-height: 1;
        padding: 16px 20px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item-has-children {
        cursor: pointer;    
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item-has-children > a {
        margin-right: 60px;
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu > .menu-item-has-children:before {
        content: "\f347";
        float: right;
        font: normal 16px/1 'dashicons';
        height: 16px;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        right: 0;
        text-align: right;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-open.menu-item-has-children:before {
        content: "\f343";
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .sub-menu {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        left: auto;
        margin: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        position: relative;
        -moz-transition:    opacity .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:     opacity .4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:      opacity .4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
        transition:         opacity .4s ease-in-out;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 25px;
    }

    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .sub-menu li a,
    .main-nav-menu.responsive-menu .sub-menu li a:hover {
        padding: 16px 20px;
        position: relative;
        text-transform: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should show your CSS code.

Comment: If you want it for both less than 768px and higher than 769px, then why to write an if condition?

Comment: Added CSS. The code is also used for a mobile menu but i wanted to also use the mobile menu on desktops.

Comment: then remove media query filter, so it would be applied for all screens

Comment: The problem is with the toggle which only works on screen widths less than 768px